# Which part sets `Content-Type` to `text/HTML` in response

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Here is some Laravel code for a route:

```
Route::get('a', function() {
    return 'hello';
});
```

Calling this route, the `Content-Type` header value is `text/HTML`.

Where does this default behavior come from? Is it set by:

- Nginx?
- PHP?
- Laravel?

Comment: Why do you care? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Symphony does that in `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response` which is the base class of laravel's response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel extends Symphony's requests/responses but is still tied heavily on their default behaviour. This particular feature is based on Symphony's [Response::prepare](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/Response.php#L263) function.

```
public function prepare(Request $request)
{
    //does a lot of things, would not go into detail
        // Content-type based on the Request
        if (!$headers->has('Content-Type')) {
            $format = $request->getRequestFormat();
            if (null !== $format && $mimeType = $request->getMimeType($format)) {
                $headers->set('Content-Type', $mimeType);
            }
        }
 //Does a lot more things
}
```

This is based on the `$request->getMimeType($format)` function and `$format` comes from `$request->getRequestFormat()`

```
public function getRequestFormat($default = 'html')
{
    if (null === $this->format) {
        $this->format = $this->attributes->get('_format');
    }
    return null === $this->format ? $default : $this->format;
}
```

Note how the default is "html" when there's no request format explicitly set. It also will only be set if you haven't already explicitly set it.

The mime types are based on a lookup initialized at https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/Request.php#L1844

The framework does go a level beyond this and provide alternative response types like e.g. [`JsonResponse`](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/JsonResponse.php) (what laravel uses when you do `response()->json()`) and this response uses a different default.

Answer (score 0):

laravel will automatically convert the string into a full HTTP response.

I found this method in symfony/http-foundation/response.php. May be this method is used to create response header.

```
 public function prepare(Request $request)
 {
    $headers = $this->headers;

    if ($this->isInformational() || $this->isEmpty()) {
        $this->setContent(null);
        $headers->remove('Content-Type');
        $headers->remove('Content-Length');
    } else {
        // Content-type based on the Request
       if (!$headers->has('Content-Type')) {
            $format = $request->getRequestFormat();
            if (null !== $format && $mimeType = $request->getMimeType($format)) {
                $headers->set('Content-Type', $mimeType);
            }
        }

        // Fix Content-Type
        $charset = $this->charset ?: 'UTF-8';
        if (!$headers->has('Content-Type')) {
            $headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset='.$charset);
        } elseif (0 === stripos($headers->get('Content-Type'), 'text/') && false === stripos($headers->get('Content-Type'), 'charset')) {
            // add the charset
            $headers->set('Content-Type', $headers->get('Content-Type').'; charset='.$charset);
        }

        // Fix Content-Length
        if ($headers->has('Transfer-Encoding')) {
            $headers->remove('Content-Length');
        }

        if ($request->isMethod('HEAD')) {
            // cf. RFC2616 14.13
            $length = $headers->get('Content-Length');
            $this->setContent(null);
            if ($length) {
                $headers->set('Content-Length', $length);
            }
        }
    }

    // Fix protocol
    if ('HTTP/1.0' != $request->server->get('SERVER_PROTOCOL')) {
        $this->setProtocolVersion('1.1');
    }

    // Check if we need to send extra expire info headers
    if ('1.0' == $this->getProtocolVersion() && false !== strpos($this->headers->get('Cache-Control'), 'no-cache')) {
        $this->headers->set('pragma', 'no-cache');
        $this->headers->set('expires', -1);
    }

    $this->ensureIEOverSSLCompatibility($request);

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The header value is set by laravel when you use route. Here's the excerpts from `symfony/http-foundation/Response.php`

```
public function __construct($content = '', $status = 200, $headers = array())
{
    $this->headers = new ResponseHeaderBag($headers);
    $this->setContent($content);
    $this->setStatusCode($status);
    $this->setProtocolVersion('1.0');

    /* RFC2616 - 14.18 says all Responses need to have a Date */
    if (!$this->headers->has('Date')) {
        $this->setDate(\DateTime::createFromFormat('U', time()));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also in https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/Response.php#L263 `prepare` does that when preparing the response

Comment: Thanks! I can't see anything about `Content-Type`in your answer, did I missed something?

Comment: @apokryfos I think you are right, feel free to post your comment as an answer.

Comment: `$this->setContent($content);`